# How to log or print request received with gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

Example:

```
func createOrUpdateInfluencer(c *gin.Context) { }
```

How to print the data in the request received in my function?
In my case, I am supposed to receive JSON, how to print it without knowing what it looks like?

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Request

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just read and print the body is ok:

```
func createOrUpdateInfluencer(c *gin.Context) {
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    println(string(body))
}
```

Or if you just want to peek it in middleware, you can put it back after read:

```
func createOrUpdateInfluencer(c *gin.Context) {
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    println(string(body))

    c.Request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
}
```

Comment: I'm Getting empty response

Comment: @HariPrasanth maybe your request body is actually empty, you can judge by compare with http.Nobody:

if c.Request.Body == http.NoBody {
  println("body is empty")
}

Answer (score 1):

by using `c.Request` you can access to your request object, then print/log everything you must, like the headers:

```
fmt.Println(g.Request.Header)
fmt.Println(g.Request.Host)
// etc
```